How to create an interactive button collapse
Currently trying to create a sort of interactive grid of buttons with logos that when clicked, triggers a window to open up at the bottom of the button which reveals a description about the logo that you clicked.
Managed get it! my problem however is that when i tried applying margin or padding to the description, toggling the buttons cause a sort of jerking animation while opening and closing it.
Any suggestions would be helpful!


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Skill collapse -->
<div class="container" id="skillContainer">
  <!-- 1st row buttons -->
  <div class="row mt-5 mb-2">
    <div class="col-3">
      <a href="#html" class="btn border border-dark skill-btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="Images/html.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <a href="#css" class="btn border border-dark skill-btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="Images/CSS.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <a href="#javascript" class="btn border border-dark skill-btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="Images/JS.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <a href="#react" class="btn border border-dark skill-btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="Images/React.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 1st row description -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="html" class="collapse skill-description p-5" data-bs-parent="#skillContainer">
        <h1>HTML</h1>
        <p>Hypertext Markup Language is the standard markup language for documents designed to be displayed in a web browser. It defines the content and structure of web content. It is often assisted by technologies such as Cascading Style Sheets and scripting
          languages such as JavaScript.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="css" class="collapse skill-description" data-bs-parent="#skillContainer">
      <h1>CSS</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, laudantium.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="javascript" class="collapse skill-description" data-bs-parent="#skillContainer">
      <h1>Javascript</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, laudantium.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="react" class="collapse skill-description" data-bs-parent="#skillContainer">
      <h1>React</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, laudantium.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 2nd row buttons -->
  <div class="row my-5">
    <div class="col-3">
      <a href="#node" class="btn border border-dark skill-btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="Images/node.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <a href="#vue" class="btn border border-dark skill-btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="Images/Vue.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <a href="#sql" class="btn border border-dark skill-btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="Images/SQL.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <a href="#angular" class="btn border border-dark skill-btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="Images/Angular.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 2nd row description -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="node" class="collapse skill-description" data-bs-parent="#skillContainer">
        <h1>Node.js</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, laudantium.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="vue" class="collapse skill-description" data-bs-parent="#skillContainer">
      <h1>Vue</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, laudantium.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="sql" class="collapse skill-description" data-bs-parent="#skillContainer">
      <h1>MySQL</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, laudantium.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="angular" class="collapse skill-description" data-bs-parent="#skillContainer">
      <h1>Angular</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, laudantium.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>




BS collapse elements don't do well with margin or padding. Don't apply the padding on the .collapse element itself - wrap the content into an additional div container, and give that one the padding.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
